# Does a re-index update statistics?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2012, index-tuning, statistics

I've been doing the MS10775A course this past week and one question that came up that the trainer couldn't answer reliably is:

> Does a re-index update the statistics?

We found discussions online arguing both that it does and that it doesn't.

Comment: It's useful to note that a `REINDEX` does update column statistics as a side-effect of rebuilding the index - you don't **need** to update the statistics. The data in the table does not change. It's the same data, it only a) moved it's location on the spinning platter (when a page is reorganized), or b) sitting in a different page (in the case of a re-build). So: a re-index **does** update (some) statistics: there's no **need** to do it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can keep the following in mind when caring about updating statistics (copied from [Rebuilding Indexes vs. Updating Statistics (Benjamin Nevarez)](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/rebuilding-indexes-vs-updating-statistics/)

1. By default, the `UPDATE STATISTICS` statement uses only a sample of records of the table. Using `UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN` will scan the entire table.
2. By default, the `UPDATE STATISTICS` statement updates both index and column statistics. Using the `COLUMNS` option will update column statistics only. Using the `INDEX` option will update index statistics only.
3. **Rebuilding an index**, for example by using `ALTER INDEX … REBUILD` will also update index statistics with the equivalent of using `WITH FULLSCAN` **unless** [the table is partitioned, in which case the statistics are only sampled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/sql-server-2012-partitioned-table-statistics-update-behavior-change-when-rebuilding-index) (applies to SQL Server 2012 and later).
4. Statistics that were manually created using `CREATE STATISTICS` are not updated by any `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` operation, including `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD`.  `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD` does update statistics for the clustered index, if one is defined on the table being rebuilt.
5. **Reorganizing an index**, for example using `ALTER INDEX … REORGANIZE` does not update any statistics.

The short answer is that you need to use `UPDATE STATISTICS` to update column statistics and that an index rebuild will update only index statistics.  You can force an update to all statistics on a table, including index-stats and manually created stats, with the `UPDATE STATISTICS (tablename) WITH FULLSCAN;` syntax.

The following code illustrates the rules encapsulated above:

First, we'll create a table with a couple of columns, and a clustered index:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable
(
    rn int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT pk
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    , i int NOT NULL INDEX i 
    , d sysname NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cx ON dbo.SomeTable (i, d);

CREATE STATISTICS d ON dbo.SomeTable (d) WITH FULLSCAN;

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (d, i)
SELECT c1.name, c1.id
FROM sys.syscolumns c1;
```

This query shows the date when each stats object was last updated:

```
SELECT ObjectName = sc.name + N'.' + o.name
    , StatsName = s.name
    , StatsDate = STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id)
FROM sys.stats s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE sc.name = N'dbo'
    AND o.name = N'SomeTable';
```

The results show no updates have yet taken place, which is correct since we just created the table:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║  ObjectName   ║ StatsName ║ StatsDate ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ cx        ║ NULL      ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ i         ║ NULL      ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ pk        ║ NULL      ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ d         ║ NULL      ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Let's rebuild the entire table, and see if that updates stats:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable REBUILD;

SELECT ObjectName = sc.name + N'.' + o.name
    , StatsName = s.name
    , StatsDate = STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id)
FROM sys.stats s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE sc.name = N'dbo'
    AND o.name = N'SomeTable';
```

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║  ObjectName   ║ StatsName ║        StatsDate        ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ cx        ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.590 ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ i         ║ NULL                    ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ pk        ║ NULL                    ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ d         ║ NULL                    ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

The results show only the *clustered index* stats were updated.

Next, we perform a discrete `UPDATE STATS` operation:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.SomeTable(d) WITH FULLSCAN;

SELECT ObjectName = sc.name + N'.' + o.name
    , StatsName = s.name
    , StatsDate = STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id)
FROM sys.stats s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE sc.name = N'dbo'
    AND o.name = N'SomeTable';
```

As you can see, we've just updated the stats on the `d` column:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║  ObjectName   ║ StatsName ║        StatsDate        ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ cx        ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.590 ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ i         ║ NULL                    ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ pk        ║ NULL                    ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ d         ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.597 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Now, we'll update stats on the entire table:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.SomeTable WITH FULLSCAN;

SELECT ObjectName = sc.name + N'.' + o.name
    , StatsName = s.name
    , StatsDate = STATS_DATE(s.object_id, s.stats_id)
FROM sys.stats s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE sc.name = N'dbo'
    AND o.name = N'SomeTable';
```

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║  ObjectName   ║ StatsName ║        StatsDate        ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ cx        ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.600 ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ i         ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.600 ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ pk        ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.603 ║
║ dbo.SomeTable ║ d         ║ 2018-09-17 14:09:13.607 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

As you can see, the only way to be certain all the stats are updated is to either update each one manually, or to update the entire table with `UPDATE STATISTICS (table);`.

Comment: @JeremyWeir - as you can see from the example code I just added to the question above, the only statistics updated are those explicitly updated either through either an `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` or an `UPDATE STATISTICS` statement.  If the table itself is rebuilt, only the clustered index statistics are updated.  FYI, a primary key and a clustered index are not necessarily supported by the same index object.

Comment: First link seems to be broken, so here it is - 
http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/rebuilding-indexes-vs-updating-statistics/

Answer (score 9):

The Microsoft Docs page for SQL Server statistics [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-2017#after-maintenance-operations):

> Operations such as rebuilding, defragmenting, or reorganizing an index do not change the distribution of data. Therefore, **you do not need to update statistics after performing ALTER INDEX REBUILD, DBCC DBREINDEX, DBCC INDEXDEFRAG, or ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE operations**. The Query Optimizer updates statistics when you rebuild an index on a table or view with ALTER INDEX REBUILD or DBCC DBREINDEX, however this statistics update is a byproduct of re-creating the index. The Query Optimizer does not update statistics after DBCC INDEXDEFRAG or ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE operations.